# Debugging shared libraries remotely with gdb/gdbserver

Tags: linux, gdb, shared-libraries, arm, remote-debugging

My question is about remote debugging an application on an embedded arm processor using gdb/gdbserver.

I can debug the application itself, but the application dynamically links to a shared library which implements an in house communications protocol.  I want to be able to set breakpoints within the shared library functions so try to figure out some device discovery problems.

I have made sure that the library is compiled with debug symbols and is loaded by gdb on the host side, I can list functions within the library and even set the breakpoints but as soon as I try to run the application I get an error message to the effect of:

`Cannot insert breakpoint X.  
Error accessing memory address [Hex address]: Input/output error.`

where `X` is the breakpoint number in gdb and `[Hex address]` is an address far to small to be valid.
I am using the new library on both the target and the host machine, but via `mount -o bind newlib oldlib` on the target from an nfs mount.
Does anyone have an idea about what could be wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging shared libraries with gdbserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611194/debugging-shared-libraries-with-gdbserver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess: you loaded the shared library into host `GDB` at incorrect address.

Instead of explicitly loading it into GDB, use `"set stop-on-solib-event on"`, wait for the library to get loaded (`info shared` will tell you current list of loaded libraries), and *then* set the breakpoints.

Answer (score 6):

I see this question is from 2009, but the current answers are out-of-date, so here's an update:

@Employed Russian suggested that you must use `stop-on-solib-event`.  This is no longer true; NDK r8d supports pending breakpoints in yet-to-be-loaded solibs.

@Brent Piddy says that `stop-on-solib-event` doesn't work with gdbserver.  This is also no longer true since at least r8c.  My company has a product that relies on this NDK behavior from GDB, we would be in big trouble without it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to set pending breakpoints that will get resolved after the shared object library is loaded

```
set breakpoint pending on
```

Sadly you can not use "set stop-on-solib-event on" for gdbserver remote debugging since gdbserver does not recognize/send solib events.  I have had to just issue a set solib-search-path or set sysroot command to get gdb to load all of the shared library symbols after hitting a breakpoint on main.

Answer (score 0):

**Run up to `main` and then `set solib-search-path .`**

Otherwise, `gdbserver` stops at the dynamic loader, before the libraries are loaded. At `main`, they should be ready for GDB.

More details: [Debugging shared libraries with gdbserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611194/debugging-shared-libraries-with-gdbserver/45252113#45252113)