# Debugging shared libraries with gdbserver

Tags: linux, gdb, shared-libraries, gdbserver

I am using gdbserver on target and CodeSourcery IDE.  My hardware is a gumstix with a omap3530.

I can step through code in my main application but if I attempt to step into a function in a shared library I get memory address and a debugger terminates.

This is my library that is compiled and copied to the /lib folder on the target system.(it does have debug symbols)  I have attempted to use the .gbdinit file to set solib-absolute-prefix /lib

Here are the warnings from the gdb trace:

```
903,056 13-gdb-set sysroot-on-target /lib
903,065 13^done
903,065 (gdb) 
903,065 14-target-select remote 192.168.1.101:2345
903,114 =thread-group-started,id="i1",pid="42000"
903,114 =thread-created,id="1",group-id="i1"
903,115 15-list-thread-groups --available
903,120 16-list-thread-groups
903,128 &"warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.\nGDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers\nand track explicitly loaded dynamic code."
903,128 &"\n"
```

Which leads to

```
903,395 &"Error while mapping shared library sections:\n"
903,397 &"/lib/libCoreLib.so: Invalid argument.\n"
903,399 =library-loaded,id="/lib/libCoreLib.so",target-name="/lib/libCoreLib.so",hostname="/lib/libCoreLib.so",low-address="0x0",high-address="0x0",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"
```

Comment: See if this article helps: http://www.fayewilliams.com/2013/01/31/gdb-unable-to-find-dynamic-linker-breakpoint-function/

Answer (score 6):

You can debug with the library installed on your host, provided the debugging machine is also the development machine. In that case, you use set sysroot instead of set sysroot-on-target. For example :

```
set sysroot /home/username/.../rootfs/
```

where `/home/username/.../rootfs/` contains a copy of your target filesystem

I think you should also specify `/` instead of `/lib`

Comment: My host debugging machine is a windows box so I am unsure where my rootfs would be located on it. thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Target with debug symbols**

This is the simplest method to get working, and it is specially useful when you are developing one particular shared library.

First copy the test executable and shared library to the target *with* debug information:

- check with `readelf ----debug-dump=decodedline libmyib.so`: [How can I tell if a library was compiled with -g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999654/how-can-i-tell-if-a-library-was-compiled-with-g)
- I recommend using an NFS server on host, so that the compiled output gets automatically uploaded after compilation

Then on target:

```
gdbserver --multi :1234 ./executable_name
```

Host:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb -q -nh \
  -ex "target extended-remote target-hostname-or-ip:1234" \
  -ex "file ./executable_name" \
  -ex 'tb main' \
  -ex 'c' \
  -ex 'set solib-search-path .'
```

`sharedlibrary libmylib.so` also works.

The problem I had was that `gdbserver` stops at the dynamic loader, before `main`, and the dynamic libraries are not yet loaded at that point, and so GDB does not know where the symbols will go in memory yet.

GDB appears to have some mechanisms to automatically load shared library symbols, and if I compile for host, and run `gdbserver` locally, running to `main` is not needed. But on the ARM target, that is the most reliable thing to do.

Target `gdbserver` 7.12-6, host `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb` 7.6.1 from Linaro.

**Target libraries without debug symbols**

It is common to strip target libraries before deployment on embedded targets, since debug information makes them *way* larger.

For example, Buildroot does that by default, but you can disable it with `BR2_STRIP_none=y`.

You can identify this scenario by running:

```
info shared
```

Which shows something like:

```
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7df7f90  0x00007ffff7dfcdd7  Yes (*)     target:/lib/ld64-uClibc.so.0
0x00007ffff7b3a9b0  0x00007ffff7bbe05d  Yes (*)     target:/lib/libc.so.0
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
```

so there are asterisks (`*`) for both of the libraries which says that debug information is missing.

If that is the case, then you have to tell GDB to use the shared libraries on host *before* they were stripped.

Buildroot for example makes that easy for us, as it maintains the `staging` directory which contains the shared libraries before they were stripped and in the same relative paths as in the target:

```
set sysroot buildroot/output/staging/
```

When this option is set, `gdb` immediately searches for libraries in the host instead of target, and finds `/lib/libc.so.0` at the path `buildroot/output/staging/` + `/lib/libc.so.0`:

```
Reading symbols from buildroot/output/staging/lib/ld64-uClibc.so.0...done.
Reading symbols from buildroot/output/staging/lib/libc.so.0...done.
```

TODO: I don't think you can set more than one `sysroot`, so all your shared libraries must be placed in their correct relative paths as in the target image.

If you check the bad default sysroot, you will see:

```
show sysroot
```

give:

```
target:
```

which means that `gdb` searches for shared libraries on the target root `/` by default.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue was encountered while debugging. The debug was hanging up. Configuration is as follows

**Host**: Ubuntu 12.04LTS

**IDE**: Eclipse Kepler

**Target**: Beaglebone Black / ARM A8

**OS**: Angstrom

**Solution**

**Update libraries and includes**

Select properties for project in Eclipse

- C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > (include TAB) GNU C > Add > Files
  systems > / > usr Change from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4/6/include
  to /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include
- C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > (Include TAB) GNU C++> Add >
  Files systems > / > usr   /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.6.3/arm-linux-gnueabi
- C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > (Library Paths TAB) > Add > Files
  systems > / > usr /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/lib

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

If the 'debug-file-directory' variable in GDB is set incorrectly,
then the reported error messages contains:
  warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.

The root filesystem of the target is located on my host PC at
/opt/arm-linux-gnueabihf-rootfs

The following two commands helped me to get remote debugging working
via gdbserver using GDB (v7.11.1):

```
set debug-file-directory /opt/arm-linux-gnueabihf-rootfs/usr/lib/debug
set sysroot /opt/arm-linux-gnueabihf-rootfs
```

I've noticed that if 'sysroot' has a trailing slash in the path,
then GDB fails to use it.You will see this (incorrect output) after connecting to the remote target:

```
Reading /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 from remote target...
```

or

```
Reading symbols from /opt/arm-linux-gnueabihf-rootfs/lib/ld-linux-
armhf.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done
```

instead of the correct output:

```
Reading symbols from /opt/arm-linux-gnueabihf-rootfs/lib/ld-linux-
armhf.so.3...
Reading symbols from /opt/arm-linux-gnueabihf-rootfs/usr/lib/debug/
lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.23.so...done.
```

Regards,
Frikkie Thirion