# Breakpoints when connecting to gdbserver through eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, gdb, breakpoints, gdbserver

I'm trying to debug an application that links to some standard libraries that are not the standard system ones (that is, it uses a different sysroot) by manually creating a gdbserver and connecting to it through eclipse cdt with the remote debugging debug configuration. While I can connect to the server and run the program to the end (I see the programs stdout), it fails if I try to stop exectuion upon connection with the error message:

```
Failed to execute MI command:
-exec-continue
Error message from debugger back end:
Warning:\nCannot insert breakpoint -1.\nTemporarily disabling shared library
breakpoints:\nbreakpoint #-1\nCannot insert breakpoint 1.\nError accessing 
memory address 0x804a814: Unknown error -1.\n
```

I have manged to get it to recoginze and stop at breakpoints set after program startup, however. If I have any set at startup though, I will get a similar error to the one above for each breakpoint.

If I connect to it by using gdb on the command line, I have no isssue working with breakpoints. What am I missing here?

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689602/debugging-shared-libraries-remotely-with-gdb-gdbserver